# Hyperplane equation in SVM using Matlab

Tags: svm

I want to get a equation of hyperplane in SVM classifier using Matlab in the case of linear separable data which is the easiest case. Actually I do not want to use Kernel function.
Is there any way to find the equation of hyperplane in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

All you need can be computed from kernel and support vectors. Matlab stores them in `svmStruct`. Just call the `svmStrain` function with `autscale` on `false`.

```
% parameters from svmStruct
w1 = dot(svmStruct.Alpha, svmStruct.SupportVectors(:,1));
w2 = dot(svmStruct.Alpha, svmStruct.SupportVectors(:,2));
bias = svmStruct.Bias;

% y = a*x + b
a = -w1/w2;
b = -svmStruct.Bias/w2;
```

See also:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/276146

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146212/how-to-plot-a-hyper-plane-in-3d-for-the-svm-results/19969412#19969412

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549714/hyperplane-in-svm-classifier

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i was wondering if you introduce me a data set which is linearly separable.

Comment: i don't know a public (large) data set that is linearly separable. But there are many simple ones, like the Fisher Iris Data Set. It's included in matlab:

load fisheriris
gscatter(meas(:,1), meas(:,2), species,'rgb','osd');
xlabel('Sepal length');
ylabel('Sepal width');
N = size(meas,1);

Comment: thank you so much. However i need large data set for my research.

Comment: Then i suggest you take a look at kaggle.com. There are a lot of large datasets you can use.